# Redirect Domain with URL to Subdomain with URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I wanted to redirect https://www.domain.rs to https://mysite.domain.rs AND  https://www.mysite.rs/this_is_some_page.html to https://mysite.domain.rs/this_is_some_page.html... How can I do it?

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite\.rs$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.domain.rs/ [L,R=302]
```

But this only redirects me to https://mysite.domain.rs regardless of what U. R. L. continues after the /. I wanted it to be redirected to whatever U. R. L. is entered as https://www.domain.rs/this_is_my_page.php to https://mysite.domain.rs/this_is_my_page.php

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.domain.rs/ [L,R=302]
```

Should be :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mysite.domain.rs/$1 [L,R=302]
```

This pasrt `^(.*)$` pattren(Regex) is to match against the URI of the current request and the substitution `https://mysite.domain.rs/$1` is the location you want rewrite to so , this regex `^(.*)$` will be presented by `$1`.

Clear browser cache then test if every thing is Ok , change `[L,R=302]` to `[L,R=301]` to be permenant redirection .